# Stored procedure using Dynamic SQL to create new table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

The question is as follows: create a stored procedure (`NEW_TABLE`) with two strings as input parameters:

- String 1: Name of the table to be generated
- String 2: Name of columns and their datatypes.

For example: `'ID Number, ProductName varchar2(50), Quantity'`

I implemented the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERATE_NEW_TABLE
    (TEMP_PRODS varchar2, COLUMNS_DATATYPES varchar2)
is
begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'CREATE TABLE '||TEMP_PRODS||'('||COLUMNS_DATATYPES||')';
end;
```

I called it as follows:

```
EXEC GENERATE_NEW_TABLE('PRODUCTS','ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCAR2(50), QUANTITY')
```

The procedure was created without compilation error, but when I executed this procedure there was error

> missing right parenthesis

Kindly share how can I resolve this. I'm only required to take two strings as input parameters for procedure.

Comment: We will not answer this until you show what is **actual** parameter values are of the failing call

Comment: your column `QUANTITY` does not have data type

Comment: I added the datatype still same error.

Comment: I was wondering if I have created the stored procedure accurately or not.

Comment: your `VARCAR2` is not declared properly. I can fiddle it just fine

Comment: While this obvious homework assignment may be able to teach several minor bits, I do hope that the lessons is _NOT_ that this is a good way to create tables.  As a business requirement, it is atrocious.  It is very very VERY rare to have a justification for using dynamic SQL to create objects in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with dynamic SQL, **always** display what you're going to execute (using `dbms_output.put_line`). Only if it is OK, then execute (immediate) it.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERATE_NEW_TABLE
  2      (TEMP_PRODS varchar2, COLUMNS_DATATYPES varchar2)
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    l_str :=
  7      'CREATE TABLE '||TEMP_PRODS||'('||COLUMNS_DATATYPES||')';
  8    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
  9    --execute immediate l_str;     --> don't run it until you make sure L_STR is correct
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> EXEC GENERATE_NEW_TABLE('PRODUCTS','ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCAR2(50), QUANTITY')
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCAR2(50), QUANTITY)    --> this will be executed

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Statement you're about to execute is

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCAR2(50), QUANTITY)
                                              -------              ---
                                              typo             missing datatype
```

Does it look OK to you? Doesn't to me (and other as well).

When fixed:

```
SQL> EXEC GENERATE_NEW_TABLE('PRODUCTS','ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(50), QUANTITY NUMBER')
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(50), QUANTITY NUMBER)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Does `CREATE TABLE` look OK now? Yes, it does. So uncomment `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` from the procedure and repeat everything:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GENERATE_NEW_TABLE
  2      (TEMP_PRODS varchar2, COLUMNS_DATATYPES varchar2)
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    l_str :=
  7      'CREATE TABLE '||TEMP_PRODS||'('||COLUMNS_DATATYPES||')';
  8    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
  9    execute immediate l_str;
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC GENERATE_NEW_TABLE('PRODUCTS','ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(50), QUANTITY NUMBER')
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS(ID Number, PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(50), QUANTITY NUMBER)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> DESC PRODUCTS
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------
 ID                                                             NUMBER
 PRODUCT_NAME                                                   VARCHAR2(50)
 QUANTITY                                                       NUMBER

SQL>
```

The table is now created.